# Unable to access elements of modal [kind of bootstrap] in Selenium javascript

Tags: selenium

I am not able to enter email and password textboxes available in below modal window....

steps:

1. Goto https://moneybhai.moneycontrol.com/
2. click Skip button
3. Click Play Now button
4. Modal window appears
5. Enter email and password

Kindly help... since new to selenium.

Using below line to switch to frames

`driver.switchTo().frame('myframe')`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)                                 

driver.get("https://moneybhai.moneycontrol.com/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//a[.='skip'])[1]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#loginbtn"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#myframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.textfieldbox.PR input#email"))).send_keys("a")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.textfieldbox.PR.usepwd input#pwd"))).send_keys("a"+Keys.ENTER)
```

There was an iframe you needed to switch to.

```
<iframe height="495px" width="320px" id="myframe" onload="resizeframe();" border="0px" style="margin-top: 50px;" src="https://accounts.moneycontrol.com/mclogin/?d=2"></iframe>
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks Arundeep for reply.  
Have done same steps in Java instead of Python. However, its not entering values in email and password. Switch to frame is getting pass... Kindly help...  
  
Note: If possible share Java code instead of Python

Comment: Can you put the sending keys in your question.

Comment: Able to enter values with below code and its working fine. Thanks.   

**await driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id('myframe')))**